# Google API with multi-tenancy application

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I have a single web application that's used by multiple customers that have their respective URLs.

We're in the process of integrating google accounts via Google API with OAuth2.

Right now we have a single project/application registered that's used by all systems.

The problem is if same account is connected on multiple systems, token is overwritten since there is a single project. Same thing if account is disconnected from system A and it's also connected on system B, system B stops working because Google API project/application is the same.

I'm wondering if there is a workaround to have multiple tokens/connections per account with a single application, or the only way to accomplish that is having one project per system and I'll need to programmatically create a project and setup everything accordingly when a new system is built.